# PerformBatchUpdates for collection view completion handler not being executed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, mobile

Interesting problem I am running into currently. When invoking the performBatchUpdates method on an instance of a UICollectionView certain cases cause the completion handler to not be executed.

```
collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
            collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)
        }) { _ in
            if self.delegate.responds(to: #selector(self.delegate.sectionNeedsToBeHidden)) {
                self.delegate.sectionNeedsToBeHidden?()
            }
        }
    }
```

When performing an insertion to the `collection view` the completion handler is not invoked. However, when the same logic is executed except the line `collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPaths)` is changed to `collectionView.deleteItems(at: indexPaths)` the completion handler is then invoked. My current guess as to why this is happening is something regarding the previous state of the collection view and it is only registering a change to the data source upon deletion therefore, causing the completion handler to be invoked. That solution however, is not definitive as to why the `completionHandler` for `performBatchUpdates` is only being invoked upon the deletion of items and not the insertion of items. If anyone has any insights on this exact problem or in general of how the `performBatchUpdates` work I would appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you insert a row or delete an item from collection view you must have to update a number of items data like below code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.myItems.count
}
```

`self.myItems.count` need to update first. So First update your items count then perform batch update.